# Display selected documents using picklistcollection

Tags: lotusscript

I have an agent that i can initialize using a action in view.

Code I have in agent:

```vb
Dim sesija As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim collection As NotesDocumentCollection
Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
Set db = sesija.CurrentDatabase

Set collection = workspace.Picklistcollection(PICKLIST_CUSTOM, True, "", _
  "Prakse2015/Uzdevums_Maris", "kategorijas", "Virsraksts", _
  "Apakšvirsraksts", "")
```

I know that few of those lines are not necessary. What it does now it that it displays all documents in the view. What i'm wondering about is that is there a way how I can display only the selected documents using picklistcollection?

Comment: Why do you want to display the selected documents in a picklist? you can act on the selected documents directly using your agent? please explain

Comment: @ThomasAdrian I want to select them so only the selected documents would appear in the window that opens. From there I will try to find a way how to manipulate with the documents categories.

Comment: Yes, but why not manipulate the "document categories" based on the selected documents in view? no need to use a picklist?

Comment: @ThomasAdrian I have to use it because that's for a exercise.

Comment: ok, I see. the problem is that you can't really do what you want, picklist collection only show all documents or documents that belong to a category. you need to use something else, like pickliststring or a dialog. You can send all the unids to the dialog and process them.

Comment: @ThomasAdrian i tried to use the pickliststring method and I get object variable not set error all the time. Any advice where should I look for tutorials or something? I've been stuck with this exercise for 2 days now I got absolutrly nothing

Comment: There are examples in the documentations you can use. I am not sure pickliststring do what you need. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_PICKLISTSTRINGS_METHOD_4229_ABOUT.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a folder to show in your Picklistcollection. Just create a folder with the same design as your view. In your code first empty the folder using the following code:

```
Set folder = db.GetView( "NameOfPicklistFolder" )
Call folder.AllEntries.RemoveAllFromFolder ( "NameOfPicklistFolder" )
```

Then put your selected documents in the folder:

```
Set dc = db.UnprocessedDocuments
Call dc.PutAllInFolder( "NameOfPicklistFolder" )
```

And use this folder instead of the view:

```
Set collection = workspace.Picklistcollection(PICKLIST_CUSTOM, True, "", _
  "Prakse2015/Uzdevums_Maris", "NameOfPicklistFolder", "Virsraksts", _
  "Apakšvirsraksts", "")
```

This will work as long as there is only one user using this functionality at the same time (no problem in case of an exercise). If there is more than one user, then you need one folder per each user (e.g. using a Shared Private on First use folder aka SPOFU), otherwise the second user will update the folder content and the first user will see the documents of the second user...

Comment: thanks for the help. I tried to use your code but all I get is a error at second line- "NOT A MEMBER: ALLENTRIES" how can i fix it?

Comment: How did you declare the variable? and what does the debugger say? Did you create a folder?